# Angular js : Column based search not working

Tags: angularjs

I have to display data in a 5 columns in a table :

- Code
- List item
- Online Name
- Offline Name
- Date Created

Upto this part is fine. Data are being displayed on the grid/table.

But **I have to implement column based search** , where the search text is provided in a text box (named/ng-model named 'query', plz find the component definition below)  and I have to select the name of the column from the a dropdown.  I am providing the code that I tried .

My table in jsp looks like this:

```
<table  id="attrTable" class="table table-fixedheader table-striped "  >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="5%" >Select</th>
        <th width="15%" > Code</th>
        <th width="45%" > Online Name</th>
        <th width="10%" > Offline Name</th>
        <th width="10%" > Date Created</th>
        <th width="15%"> Action </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="height:700px">
    <tr ng-repeat="u in attrCtrl.allAttr| filter:attrCtrl.getSearchFilter(query)" >
        <td width="5%"><input id="{{u.id }}" type="checkbox" value="{{u.id }}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(u.id) > -1" ng-click="attrCtrl.toggleSelection(u)" /><span></span></td>
        <td width="15%">{{ u.attrCd}}<span></span></td>
        <td width="45%">{{ u.onlineName }}<span></span></td>
        <td width="10%">{{ u.onlineName }}<span></span></td>
        <td width="10%">{{ u.insertDate }}<span></span></td>
        <td width="15%">

        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Where **query**( which represents the text box to provide the search text)  is defined as :

```
 <input ng-model="query"  ng-style="{'height': '24px'}" type="text"  placeholder="Search" class="filterWidth .navbar-right">
```

And the **getSearchFilter function in the controller is returning hard coded String that works as filter if I replace the this function call by the returning string directly. Means it works if I create the rows in the above table as:**.

```
<tr ng-repeat="u in attrCtrl.allAttr | filter : {onlineName:'Patty'}" >
```

**But does not work if I use the the function call instead. Even though this function is returning the exact same String to be used as filter.**
This function looks like   :

```
self.getSearchFilter = function(searchText)
{
    self.filterSearch = "{onlineName:'Patty'}";

    window.alert(self.filterSearch);

    return self.filterSearch ;

}
```

In the controller "attributeCtrl" I defined "**searchProprties**" as :

```
self.searchProprties = [
    {option : "All", value : "search.$"},
    {option : "Code", value : "search.attrCd"},
    {option : "Online Name", value : "search.onlineName"},
    {option : "Offline Name", value : "search.onlineName"},
    {option : "Insert Date", value : "search.insertDate"}
];
```

Where "attrCd","onlineName","insertDate" are actual name of the columns.

**May I get some direction on why the filter is not working if I use the function call to get the filter string?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work by writing a function '**search**' on the **controller** (Make sure you are noticing '**query**' which represents the search text box and' **queryByProperty**' which represents the dropdown in the picture:

```
self.search = function( item )
{
    if( !self.query )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(self.queryByProperty==='attrCd' &&
        ( item.attrCd!= null && item.attrCd.toLowerCase().indexOf( self.query.toLowerCase() ) != -1 ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(self.queryByProperty==='onlineName' &&
        ( item.onlineName != null && item.onlineName.toLowerCase().indexOf( self.query.toLowerCase() ) != -1 ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(self.queryByProperty==='offlineName' &&
        ( item.offlineName != null && item.offlineName.toLowerCase().indexOf( self.query.toLowerCase() ) != -1 ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( self.queryByProperty==='all' &&
        (( item.attrCd != null && item.attrCd.toLowerCase().indexOf( self.query.toLowerCase() ) != -1 )
        || ( item.onlineName != null && item.onlineName.toLowerCase().indexOf( self.query.toLowerCase() ) != -1 )
        || ( item.offlineName != null && item.offlineName.toLowerCase().indexOf( self.query.toLowerCase() )  != -1 ))
        )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

On the **JSP** I had to make small change on the **search box** and **drop-down to select the column to search on**:

```
<input ng-model="attrCtrl.query"  ng-style="{'height': '24px'}" type="text"  placeholder="Attribute Search" class="filterWidth .navbar-right">

<select ng-model="attrCtrl.queryByProperty" ng-style="{'height': '24px'}"  >
    <option value="">Select Property</option>
    <option ng-repeat="x in attrCtrl.searchProprties" value="{{x.queryOption}}" >{{x.option}}</option>
</select>
```

And on the table the **filter should be called this way** (basically we are looking for true/false value to receive to hide/display the column):

```
<table  id="attrTable" class="table table-fixedheader table-striped "  >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="5%" >Select</th>
        <th width="15%" > Code</th>
        <th width="45%" > Online Name</th>
        <th width="10%" > Offline Name</th>
        <th width="10%" > Date Created</th>
        <th width="15%"> Action </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="height:700px">
    <tr ng-repeat="u in attrCtrl.allAttr| filter:attributeCtrl.search " >
        <td width="5%"><input id="{{u.attributeId }}" type="checkbox" value="{{u.id }}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(u.id) > -1" ng-click="attrCtrl.toggleSelection(u)" /><span></span></td>
        <td width="15%">{{ u.attributeCd}}  <span></span></td>
        <td width="45%">{{ u.onlineName }}  <span></span></td>
        <td width="10%" >{{ u.offlineName}} <span ></span></td>
        <td width="10%">{{ u.insertDate }}  <span></span></td>
        <td width="15%">


        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my '**searchProperty**' on the controller where the values for the dropdown are coming from:

```
self.searchProprties = [
    {option : "All", queryOption : "all"},
    {option : "Code", queryOption : "attrCd"},
    {option : "Online Name", queryOption : "onlineName"},
    {option : "Offline Name", queryOption : "offlineName"},
    {option : "Insert Date", queryOption : "insertDate"},
];
```